# i don't know.... how google oauth laravel resister custom?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, google-oauth

When I'm signing up using Google Auth, I would like to add an extra field(gender), to the actuals fields: name, email and password. Please show me.

```
public function callback()
{
    try {

        $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();  
        $existUser = User::where('email',$googleUser->email)->first();

        if($existUser) {
            Auth::loginUsingId($existUser->id);
        }
        else {
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $googleUser->name;
            $user->email = $googleUser->email;
            $user->password = md5(rand(1,10000));
            $user->save();
            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        }
        return redirect()->to('/home');
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

Comment: Google may or may not provide a `gender`.  If they do then great. If not, setup your callback to redirect to a page where you provide a dropdown to select the gender, save this input when you create your `google` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that, create new page and call it profile
Allow user to edit profile like name, profile picture etc along with asking about more details like gender and any other thing.

From that page you can get gender value.

This is the best way i think because google plus api not providing gender!